# Webpack hot loading not working on windows

Tags: socket.io, webpack, livereload, webpack-dev-server

Currently using this boilerplate (https://github.com/tsaiDavid/simple-redux-boilerplate). I have it up and running on my OSX machine working just fine, but on my windows machine it does not work.

Chrome console says `[HMR] connected` and then nothing else when I change a file, it seems like it does not register whenever a file is changed on my windows machine.

I run the project with `set NODE_ENV=development` and then `node devServer.js`

I remember having an issue with the Brackets IDE live reload as well because of the sockets not working properly, this might be related, as far as I know, webpack hot reload uses sockets to send the updates?

Anyways, anyone got any tips or solutions here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with spaces in the path of the files being processed by webpack.

Comment: How did you set it up to live reload in windows?

Comment: Same as any other OS. I just had an issue with the folder path. My files were located in `C:/Dropbox (TeamName)/projectName`

The space in `Dropbox (TeamName)` messed up webpack, so I just created a symlink to `C:/Dropbox-TeamName` instead and it worked.

For help to set up webpack you can check out e.g. https://github.com/WeHeartGaming/tui/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: How do you run your app? as a local server and open it in Chrome?

Comment: That specific GitHub repo is an Electron app, so I run it through Electron, but you can also just go to localhost:3000 in chrome. This is the development server: https://github.com/WeHeartGaming/tui/blob/master/webpack.server.js